# Segmentation fault (core dumped) image processing c++/opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, segmentation-fault

I want to apply a smooth to an image,for that purpose I create the function "sum" Here's my code

```
double sum(cv::Mat img, int startedX, int startedY, int w) {
double res = 0;
std::cout << "startedX= " << startedX<< "/ startedY= " << startedY<<  std::endl; 
for (int i = startedX - ((w - 1) / 2); i < startedX + ((w + 1) / 2); i++) {
  std::cout << "i= " << i <<  std::endl;    
    for (int j = startedY - ((w - 1) / 2) ; j < startedY + ((w + 1) / 2); j++) {std::cout << " j= " <<j<<  std::endl;
     if ((i >= 0 && i < img.size().width) && (j >= 0  && j < img.size().height)) {      
            res += img.at<float>(i,j); }}}
              return res;}
```

This is a portion of my main function where the program crashes :

```
for (int k = 0; k < imgSource.size().width; k++) {
 for (int l = 0; l < imgSource.size().height; l++) {
        if( (k >= 0 && k < imgSource.size().width) && (l >= 0  && l < imgSource.size().height) ) {
      std::cout << "k= "<<k <<"  l= "<<l<< " wmax= "<< wmax<<std::endl; 
      newImgMax.at<float>(k,l) =(float)sum(imgMax,k,l, wmax) / (wmax * wmax);
       }}}
```

for k=0 and l=0 the program works fine and returns a value but for k=0 and l=1 **the call of the function(sum(imgMax,0,1,1)) doesn't pass,it crashes and shows a segmentation fault core dumped**.This is my output

```
k= 0  l= 0 wmax= 1
startedX= 0/ startedY= 0
i= 0
j= 0
k= 0  l= 1 wmax= 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: OpenCV uses row, column notation for access so your `at(k, l)` should be `at(l, k)`. Same with `at(i, j)` in `sum()`. I don't know if this fixes your problem though.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply,I replaced (k,l) by (l,k) and(i,j) by (j,i) but the problem persists

Comment: After several tests I found that the call to the function "sum" is done only once independently of indexes(rows,cols) for example when I try :  std::cout << " (1,0)= " <<sum(imgMax,1, 0, wmax) <<std::endl; it returns a value and when I try :                                                                                        std::cout << " (2,3)= " <<sum(imgMax,2, 3, wmax) <<std::endl;
std::cout << " (1,0)= " <<sum(imgMax,1, 0, wmax) <<std::endl;                               it returns the result of the first and crashes after any suggestions please ?

Comment: Now I'm sure the function is called once,the problem is not about rows or colomns here's another example :

[code]
std::cout << " (4,1)= " <<sum(imgMax,4, 1, wmax) <<std::endl;
std::cout << " (2,3)= " <<sum(imgMax,2, 3, wmax) <<std::endl;
std::cout << " (1,0)= " <<sum(imgMax,1, 0, wmax) <<std::endl;
[/code]

it returns the value of the first call and crashes after

Comment: Is `(2, 3)` a valid location? Both your comments have it crashing at that coordinate.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x yeah it's valid when I put cout << " (2,3)= " <<sum(imgMax,2, 3, wmax) <<std::endl; before the other calls it returns a value,always the first call of sum returns a value and crashes after